# calling WS from ant

Tags: java, ant, jax-ws

I have written a java WS and hosted it

```
@WebService
public class DBConnectionCheck{

    @WebMethod
    public synchronized boolean dbServerState(final String SERVERNAME,final String USER_ID,final String USER_PASSWORD
            ,final String VENDOR,final String PORT,final String CONNECTOR_TYPE)
    {
             .............}
    @WebMethod
         @WebMethod
    public synchronized boolean oracleDBState(......)
         {
..............
          }
```

I had generated the stubs and wrote the client also....

```
      public class CheckRegressionStatus {



public static void main(String args[]) throws PreRequisticException
{

    Properties resourceMangerProps = new Properties();

    /**
     * Instantiate the generated Service
     */
    com.cordys.autopilot.InfraStructure.servercheck.stub.ReadInfraResourceAvaliabiltyService service1 = new com.cordys.autopilot.InfraStructure.servercheck.stub.ReadInfraResourceAvaliabiltyService();

    com.cordys.autopilot.InfraStructure.servercheck.stub.ReadInfraResourceAvaliabilty res = service1.getReadInfraResourceAvaliabiltyPort();

    /**
     * Instantiate the generated Service
     */
    com.cordys.autopilot.InfraStructure.dbstate.stub.DBConnectionCheckService                              service = new com.cordys.autopilot.InfraStructure.dbstate.stub.DBConnectionCheckService();


    com.cordys.autopilot.InfraStructure.dbstate.stub.DBConnectionCheck dbConnectionCheckProxy = service.getDBConnectionCheckPort();
```

This works perfect when called from Eclipse or Netbeans

But when I wrote an ant code to invoke it

```
<java classname="....InfraStructure.CheckRegressionStatus">                 
                    <classpath>
                        <pathelement path="XYZ.jar"/>          
                    </classpath>
</java>
```

It is throwing the following error

```
  [java] javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not f
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:194)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:747)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:201)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:104)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
  [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  [java]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:
  [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:698)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:199)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)
  [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)
  [java] Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.Provide
  [java]     at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:33)
  [java]     at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:128)
  [java]     at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:83)
  [java]     at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using JDK 1.6?

This class `com/sun/xml/internal/ws/spi/ProviderImpl` is found in JDK 1.6 `rt.jar` by default. You most likely have set Eclipse with the correct JDK, but have not set Ant to use JDK 1.6.